# source コマンドによる .bashrc の読み込みが別ターミナルに反映されないのはなぜ？

Tags: bash, shellscript

ターミナルで２つタブを開いて作業をしていました。片方のターミナルで.bashrcに変更を加え、`source ~/.bashrc`で変更を反映させました。しかし、もう片方のターミナルでその変更を確認すると変更がされていないとエラーが出ました。しかし、`source ~/.bashrc`をした方のターミナルで確認すると変更がされていることが確認できました。
なぜ２つ開かれたターミナルごとで結果が異なるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

タブごとに異なるbashが並列に起動しているからです。
あるタブのbashで`source`した結果は並列して起動している別のタブのbashへは反映されません。

`echo $$`を実行すると起動しているbashのPIDが表示されるので、`pgrep`や`pstree`などでどういう風になっているのかを調べられると思います。